# Does ampersand also function as line terminator?

Tags: shell, background-process

I know that in bash, the `&` symbol delegates a command to the background, but is it also supposed to double as a special line terminator?

To give an example of what I'm referring to, I found this line in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html

```
while read a; do echo "FIFO1: $a"; done < /tmp/fifo1 & exec 7> /tmp/fifo1
```

is the above equivalent to..?

```
while read a; do echo "FIFO1: $a"; done < /tmp/fifo1 &
exec 7> /tmp/fifo1
```

Or is there special significance to these two parts being in the same line?

Comment: @StephenKitt Ah, I see "A newline after command1 is optional." under `&` section!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read a; do echo "FIFO1: $a"; done < /tmp/fifo1 & exec 7> /tmp/fifo1
```

is indeed equivalent to

```
while read a; do echo "FIFO1: $a"; done < /tmp/fifo1 &
exec 7> /tmp/fifo1
```

`&` acts as a command separator, as well as placing the command preceding it in the background.

Strictly speaking, it acts as a [separator for items in a list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists):

> A `list` is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘`;`’, ‘`&`’, ‘`&&`’, or ‘`||`’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘`;`’, ‘`&`’, or a `newline`.